# Reference Socket.io fron Node server in Offline App with Require.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, requirejs

I am trying to use Socket.io hosted by a Node server.  I am using Require.js to manage dependencies.  My webapp is Offline capable.

When the webapp is offline, and cannot contact the node server, require.js throws an error because it cannot find the socket.io dependency.

```
GET http://mikemac.local:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js  require.js:33
Uncaught Error: Script error
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

In this case I am not using node/io for the majority of the system, just 'bonus' real time notifications.  So The app should run without it.

How can I deal with this?  I would like a way to detect that it cannot be found and then disable the socket.io functionality until a connection/refresh attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration setup fallback to other module and in the fallback indicate that it is offline:

```
requirejs.config({
    enforceDefine: true,
    paths: {
        socketio: [
            'http://mikemac.local:8000/socket.io/socket.io',
            //If the CDN location fails, load from this location
            'lib/socketoffline'
        ]
    }
});

//socketoffline
define({ offline: true});

//Later
require(['socketio'], function (socketio) {
    if (socketio.offline){
        // your library did not load:
    } else {
        // socketio loaded
    }
});
```